# What do you do if you see a cougar?

Tags: hiking, canada, cougars

Hiking on the west coast of British Columbia, there are likely to be cougars around the trails. What do you do if you see one?

Comment: Take a picture, quick!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I actually had a site bookmarked for this very reason that provided some good, sound advice. I've always heard that a cougar (mountain lion) generally doesn't let you see it unless its considering attacking.

> **100 yards away or more that is unattentive to you**
>
> - Avoid rapid movements, running, loud, excited talk.
> - Stay in groups; keep children with adults.
>
> Probability of risk is slight, provided your response is appropriate.
>
> **50 yards away with its ears up and attentive to you**
>
> - Hold small children; keep older children close to an adult.
> - Do not turn your back.
> - Look for sticks, rocks or other weapons and keep them at hand.
> - Watch the cat at all times.
>
> Probability of attack is slight for adults given proper response.
>   Probability of attack is serious for unaccompanied children.
>
> **Less than 50 yards away, staring intensely at you, or hiding;**
>
> - All of the above steps, plus place older children behind adults.
> - Seek a safer location, or one above the lion, if available.
> - Do not run.
> - Appear larger. Raise arms, objects, or jackets above your head.
> - Prepare to defend yourself.
>
> Probability of attack is substantial.
>
> **Intensely staring, crouching and/or creeping toward you**
>
> - Take all the above actions.
> - Moving slowly, position trees, boulders or other large objects between yourself and the lion.
> - Do not lose sight of the lion.
> - Smile! Show your teeth. (A woman attacked at Cuyamaca Rancho State Park may have saved herself by baring her teeth, growling and staring the lion down as it approached her).
> - Make loud, menacing sounds, like yelling and growling.
> - Throw things if the lion is close enough to hit.
> - Use lethal weapons if you have them.
> - Pepper spray may be effective if lion is downwind and close enough.
>
> Probability of risk is serious if within 20 yards.
>
> **Poised to attack**
>
> - Prepare to defend yourself in close combat
> - Fight back.
> - Make menacing noises.
> - Keep eye contact with the cat.
> - Act aggressively toward the
> - Use a stick to charge the lion, thrusting the stick toward its face.
> - No stick? Yell loud and run toward the lion with arms high.
> - Stay beyond striking distance of its paws.

Source: [Link](http://www.angelfire.com/co/KlueLass/lions/ljohnson.html)

Comment: Solid answer.  And once the lion is gone, change into some dry shorts. ;)

Answer (score 15):

I think these signs in California and elsewhere describe it quite simply:

[image: if you encounter a mountain lion]

Answer (score 7):

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VshBT5Ua4uo) is quite a good instruction.

**But beware!** This strategy might not be valid for other beasts of prey, such as lions. In a video which is now deleted, a man is instructed to be quiet and stay low not to agitate the beast.  Also, the man in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eWkLqlhxJuw) is staying low (in fact, he's almost lying) and threatening the lion with toilet paper (!) if necessary.